# populate a date field off a roll up summary

Tags: apex, roll-up-summary

I am trying to update a date field on the Account object when two roll up summaries (Total_Opportunities_Won__c & Active_Opportunities__c) enter 0. Currently our process is that we have two roll up summaries that feed from the Opportunity object and then we have 3 scheduled apex classes to update the status. What I am needing to accomplish is a way to update a date field on the Account object when both the roll up summaries equal 0. Then if the roll up summary for Active_Opportunities__c increases to 1 or greater to put todays date. Was wondering if someone might be able to help the newbie with this?

Prospect

```
global class DailyAccountProcessorProspect implements Schedulable {

global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
    List<Account> myList = [SELECT Active_Opportunities__c,Id,Total_Opportunities_Won__c FROM Account WHERE Total_Opportunities_Won__c = 0 AND Active_Opportunities__c = 0];

    if(!myList.isEmpty()) {
        for(Account l: myList) {
            l.Customer_Type__c = 'Prospect';
        }
        update myList;
    }
}
}
```

Former:

```
global class DailyAccountProcessorFormer implements Schedulable {

global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
    List<Account> myList = [SELECT Active_Opportunities__c,Id,Total_Opportunities_Won__c FROM Account WHERE Total_Opportunities_Won__c >= 1 AND Active_Opportunities__c = 0];

    if(!myList.isEmpty()) {
        for(Account l: myList) {
            l.Customer_Type__c = 'Former Customer';
        }
        update myList;
    }
}
}
```

Current:
global class DailyAccountProcessorCurrent implements Schedulable {

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
    List<Account> myList = [SELECT Active_Opportunities__c,Id,Total_Opportunities_Won__c FROM Account WHERE Total_Opportunities_Won__c >= 1 AND Active_Opportunities__c = 1];

    if(!myList.isEmpty()) {
        for(Account l: myList) {
            l.Customer_Type__c = 'Current Client';
        }
        update myList;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working this way.

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update)
 {

  if(checkRecursive.runOnce())
    {
list<Account> account_Updatelist= new list<Account>();
for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
  {
     if(acc.Total_Opportunities_Won__c>=1 && acc.Active_Opportunities__c == 0 && Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).Account_Clearing_Date__c!=null && acc.Account_Clearing_Date__c == Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).Account_Clearing_Date__c + 1)
        acc.Customer_Type__c = 'Former Client';


      else if(acc.Total_Opportunities_Won__c>=1 && acc.Active_Opportunities__c >= 1)
         acc.Customer_Type__c = 'Current Client';

      else if(acc.Total_Opportunities_Won__c==0 && acc.Active_Opportunities__c==0)
         acc.Customer_Type__c = 'Prospect';

      if(acc.Active_Opportunities__c==0)
         acc.Account_Clearing_Date__c = system.today();

      else if(acc.Active_Opportunities__c>=1)
        acc.Account_Clearing_Date__c = null;

      //  account_Updatelist.add(acc);

  }

//  if(account_Updatelist!=null && account_Updatelist.size()>0)
    //  update account_Updatelist;

  }

  }
```

With this class as well

```
public Class checkRecursive{
private static boolean run = true;
public static boolean runOnce(){
if(run){
 run=false;
 return true;
}else{
    return run;
}
}
}
```

Comment: A workflow rule ought to handle this easily.  You can include logic in a workflow field update that can evaluate the rollups and set the date appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the process builder to evaluate the fields each time the record is updated or changed, 
reference the object type
[image]

and then you can define the conditions for the fields that are modified:
[image]

and finally update the record using a formula field that evaluates to Today()
[image]

this is easily maintainable, [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_overview.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ca%2F&type=0) you can find salesforce's documentation regarding the process builder

Comment: With everything I read I thought you couldn't use process builder for a rollup summary change?